# Scanning char array and putting it in struct properly in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

Wanted to get my char array to be in a struct, but it crashes.

As I realised after, there is also a problem when scanning the array.

The input string consists of two words, name and surname, separated by a space. I haven't yet written the part where it scans the second word, so now it scans only the first.

The check lines in code have s weird output. I input "James" and it gives me "J8224a8224m8224e8224s8224" and then crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
struct base
{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    int point1;
    int point2;
};
main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    base a[n];
    char symb;
    char sym[20];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            symb = getchar();
            sym[j] = symb;
            j++;
        } while (symb != ' ');

        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) //check
            cout << sym[k] << '  ';  //check

        strcpy(sym, a[i].name);
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(sym, a[i].name);` You're copying characters into memory that does not exist yet! There's probably another problem based on the output you see.

Comment: You have pointers in the structure, but you don't make them point anywhere. Also, technically your program is not a valid C++ program, because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It's an extension in some compilers, avoid them.

Comment: `base a[n]` is gcc extension, `cout<<sym[k]<<'   '` uses two spaces so it's multi-character character

Comment: Yes, it is an unfinished program. At the moment I have the strange output of inputted string, basically I have "8224" after each character

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of pointers, raw arrays and error-prone C functions.

Comment: @BlackMoses so is the problem with the check output?

Comment: @KamilSaitov I'm just pointing that you have two spaces between `' '`, space ASCII code is 32, so it's not interpreted as character but as integer of value [SPACE] * 256 + [SPACE] = 8224. Remove one space and at least one problem should be solved.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I created a memory for a[i].name and it doesn't crash now. But when I output it, I get something reeeally weird. Sometimes weird symbols, sometimes some letters which don't seem to have enything common with the output.

Comment: @BlackMoses did that. Now 8224 doesn't appear. Thanks! Now the strcpy thing left. Would really appreciate if you helped me.

Comment: You are storing input characters in `sym[j]`, but you never terminate the string. `strcpy` expects to find a `'\0'` at the end. Everything would be *a lot*  easier if you used `std::vector` and `std::string`. For example `string name; cin >> name;` will read one word separated by whitespace. Done.

Comment: @BoPersson then can I have string type in the struct and do `cin >> a[i].name` ?

Comment: @Kamil - Sure, that would work too (as long as `a[i]` does exist).

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors:

1. You cannot use static initialization for base a[n], because variable n is not known while compiling.
2. You have to initialize a[i].name before you do strcpy.
3. You shlould use sptncpy instead of strcpy if you know lenght which is j.

You code should look like this

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    base *a = new base[n];
    char symb;
    char sym[20];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            symb = getchar();
            sym[j] = symb;
            j++;
        } while (symb != ' ');

        for (int k = 0; k<j; k++) //check
            cout << sym[k] << ' ';  //check

        a[i].name = new char[j];
        strncpy(sym, a[i].name, j);
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's worth to mention that there are C++-ish ways to accomplish this.